# SOAP vs REST when session control is needed at server side

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, wsdl

There are many questions about this choice in Stackoverflow, but I didn't find any answer considering an important fact: session control.

Let's supposse an user answering a test created by our web service. If our user can navigate between the pages of this test, we need to save for a while its status in server side (in order to auto-save answers or avoid cheating). If we do it at client side, we risk our user can cheat. We definetively lose control.

So, in this case, what's the better choice? And how about security? Can both options have the same high security level as SSL?

Thank you.

Comment: Neither is necessarily better. They can both get the job done, but your overall implementation may be very different between using a SOAP API and a RESTful API. As for security, you can make either implementation as secure as you want. It is up to you what security techniques you choose to utilize, and yes, that may very well include using HTTPS (I would definitely recommend it). I know this probably is not the response you want, so I would encourage you to ask more specific, closed-ended questions in the future.

Comment: For the example exposed above, maybe it's the most specific that I can think of, in this moment. Taking control of the status of the operations the client is doing makes me think that the SOAP option is probably the best in this case. So, is there any option in order to save status (a Session, an object persistent in memory for a while) with RESTful API?

Comment: REST is stateless. This, however, does not mean that a solution cannot be architected using RESTful APIs that meets your requirements. I work for a company that deals in complex surveys, which are not too different from a test. Our distributed system is composed of numerous RESTful APIs for delivering the surveys to the respondents and capturing their responses in a controlled and secure manner.

Comment: You can have session objects in your architecture, REST is a completely separate concern.